# Laravel 4 Form Submission and Input Retrieval

Tags: php, forms, input, laravel

I am a beginner in Laravel. I am trying to make a simple login form, by using a controller to manipulate the input. However everytime the code just ignore the controller function and keep calling the index everytime I submit. Please advise.

**Here is the code for my form**

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'CoverController@authent')) }}
<div class="col-md-3 text-box pull-left">
{{ Form::email('email', '', array('placeholder'=>'Email')); }}
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 text-box pull-left">
{{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder'=>'Password')); }}
</div>
<div class="clearfix"> </div>  
<div class="con-button">
{{ Form::submit('Sign Up / Log In'); }}
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**Below is my routes**

```
Route::get('/',array('as'=>'users','uses'=>'CoverController@index'));

Route::post('/','CoverController@authent');
```

**Here is my controller function**

```
class CoverController extends BaseController {
/**
* Display a listing of the resource.
*
* @return Response
*/
    public function index()
    {
        $view =  View::make('cover');
        return $view;
    }
    public function authent()
    {
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $pwd = Input::get('password');
        $view =  View::make('formoid')->with('email',$email)->with('password',$pwd);
        return $view;
    }
}
```

With the above code,everytime the login button is pressed, the index() function is called instead of authent(), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: how does the rendered code look like? (the opening form tag)

Comment: Does it change anything, if you change the route to      `Route::post('/',[ 'as' => 'userauth', 'uses' => 'CoverController@authent']);` and the Form opening to   `Form::open(['route' => 'userauth'])`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. No, it does not change the outcome.I just solved the problem. Apparently I just need to change the form action to another link instead of root ('/') for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/', 'method' => 'post')) }}
```

[Form Doc](http://laravel.com/docs/html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just solved the problem. Apparently I just need to change the form action to another link instead of root ('/') for it to work.

Comment: But you had root ('/') route for CoverController@authent, right? So the above code should work.

Comment: For some reason it won't work on the root, even if the controller is directed to ('/'), it is ignored.

Comment: In short, any Route::post('/') is ignored. So I have to link my form to another directory, in this case I made another directory ('/Registration') to process the form.